# Magento Add Event onlick on System Configuration Custom Module Field

Tags: magento, module, system.xml

Nowhere can I find a definition for which to search.
In mymodule **namespace/modulename/etc/system.xml** I have:

```
<faq_input translate="label">
    <label>Question Collor: </label>
    <comment>example: #000000</comment>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</faq_input>
```

I need add `onclick` event like:

```
<input type="text" onclik="code(myevent)" value="xxx" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `<frontend_model>`, for which you can find some examples in the core (eg in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml`).

The frontend model must be a block inheriting from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field`, which has a `_getElementHtml()` method where you can apply your own code to the form element before rendering it. Eg :

```
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $element->setOnclick('launchExample();');
    $html = $element->getElementHtml();
    $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">function launchExample(){ alert("This is an example"); }</script>';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more? <frontend_model> can only operate  with:_getElementHtml() What next? In now i just do this with jQuert, but i want think that with default magento this can do!

Comment: The parameter `$element` passed to `_getElementHtml()` is the form element on which you can apply what you need, including setting an `onclick` event. And if you need some custom JS, you can return it along with the base HTML value.

Comment: there need extend some mage class, oj just wirte my simple class?

Comment: Yes it's better to extend from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field`